# How do I print all lines of current file with list command in gdb?

Tags: gdb

How do I print all lines of current file with list command in gdb?
`list` command show only 10 lines by default, so I want to show all lines of current file.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `list 1,10000` where `10000` is large enough number so that the size of a file you debugging is less than this large enough number. See builtin gdb help:

```
(gdb) help list
List specified function or line.
With no argument, lists ten more lines after or around previous listing.
"list -" lists the ten lines before a previous ten-line listing.
One argument specifies a line, and ten lines are listed around that line.
Two arguments with comma between specify starting and ending lines to list.
Lines can be specified in these ways:
  LINENUM, to list around that line in current file,
  FILE:LINENUM, to list around that line in that file,
  FUNCTION, to list around beginning of that function,
  FILE:FUNCTION, to distinguish among like-named static functions.
  *ADDRESS, to list around the line containing that address.
With two args, if one is empty, it stands for ten lines away from
the other arg.

By default, when a single location is given, display ten lines.
This can be changed using "set listsize", and the current value
can be shown using "show listsize".
```